# How can I implement a digital clock in Logisim?

Tags: fpga, logisim

I'm trying to simulate a 12h-digital clock in Logisim. Here's the logic diagram:
[image: Logic Diagram of a Digital Clock]

I could simulate BCD to 7 Segment but I don't know how to create a CTR DIV 10 and CTR DIV 6 in Logisim, so I tried to look into some logic diagram and found this:
[image: CTR DIV 10 and CTR DIV 6]

[image: Counter and Decoder]

By the way, here's the structure of the CTR DIV 10 but I don't understand how it works:

And here's my approach to this implementation:
[image: Approach]
[image: Waveform]
[image: CTR DIV 10]

Any help to simulate this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is.

Comment: How to implement a CTR DIV 10(74F162) and a CTR DIV 6 in Logisim,(in order to simulate a digital clock)?

Comment: 1. The Spanish language is nice but note, that please use English. 2. It is hard to distinguish between your work and the designs that you have found online. 3. Still not sure what your question is... Be more specific and remove unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what your question is, but I try to answer what I have understood.

I suggest to make two part of simulating *CTR DIV 10*

1. Create the model of 74F162 (aka. a general purpose counter)
2. Add the overflow logic. (to make the *DIV 10*)

### 1. Create the model of 74F162

There are so many detailed counter implementation post like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/112604/103936) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_(digital)).

### 2. Add the overflow logic

To create a counter with custom modulo (period) you need to add the overflow/reset logic. This circuit will reset your counter when your counter reach the wanted maximum. (10 at *DIV 10* and 6 at *DIV 6*). Lets do the 10: You need to detect the binary 1010 (which is the decimal 10).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPM5rJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output of the circuit above will be high only when the input is decimal 10. You can connect this circuit to reset input of your counter. (Note the polarity, your counter maybe have active low reset input.)